# QNAmaker: How to enable context-only for subquestions?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I have a document pdf or docx (only accepted formats for multiturn), this contains alot of subheadings which translate to follow up prompts. This all works fine! But I would like to enable context-only for all of my prompts, because the answers are not relevant out of context.

Can I denote this in my document itself? There are way too many too manually check the button.

I could write a script that changes the contextOnly to true on the exported tsv, but this seems like it is a silly workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be any way to indicate whether a question is context-only through [the document extraction process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#create-a-multi-turn-conversation-from-a-documents-structure), so you will need to automate this with a script. If you don't want to modify the TSV directly, you can use [the QnA REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase). You can also access this API through [the Bot Framework CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/blob/master/packages/qnamaker/README.md) but I don't know if that makes anything more convenient for you.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind making a script for this but if there was an easy way to do it all it once it would've been nice.